# Ionic Popup button not visible

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying out with Ionic framework to build a small app, but the alert popup has no button on it. For some reason its not visible.

this is how it looks -

[image: app]

my controller -

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup) {
$scope.users = {};
$scope.show = function() {
var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
 title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
 template: 'It might taste good'
});
};

})
```

Please suggest what could be the reason ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `show` to `alert` and it worked.

```
$ionicPopup.show
```

to

```
$ionicPopup.alert
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add buttons to it in configuration object

```
buttons: [
  { text: 'Cancel' }
]
```

can check [Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
// An alert dialog
$scope.showAlert = function() {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
     template: 'It might taste good'
   });

   alertPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
   });
 };
```

You are missing `$ionicPopup.alert` that makes button available, not `$ionicPopup.show`.

[Reference](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)